# Windows 10 Default System Fonts

Tags: windows, fonts

Windows 10 uses Segoe UI as the default system font, but Segoe UI does not have symbols for Chinese characters. To display Chinese, the system uses the SimSun font.

My question is what system fonts does Windows use and for which characters does it use them?

I have been unable to find any exhaustive lists on this topic.

Comment: Should this be on superuser? I am asking in reference to some localization code I am writing, but in retrospect this may be the wrong place.

Comment: Pretty sure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows covers that information, though? As for "for some reason", using multiple fonts in a single family to span Unicode (which hasn't fit into a single font since v3.0, quite a long time ago =) is the only way to effect coverage.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that is the list of fonts that ship with windows, not what fonts the system uses. Also SimSun and Segoe are not in the same font family.

Comment: Ah, yeah accidentally called it a family instead of a stack. Left an answer with the information on how Windows decides to fall through which fonts when the main font doesn't support what is required of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default windows 10 always uses Segoe UI, but when a language is required that is not supported by it, Windows will fall through a prespecified fallback font stack for Segoe UI, which is stored in the Windows NT part of the registry (not the standard Windows part), at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink
```

For Segoe UI, the font stack is:

```
TAHOMA.TTF,Tahoma
MEIRYO.TTC,Meiryo UI,128,96
MEIRYO.TTC,Meiryo UI
MSGOTHIC.TTC,MS UI Gothic
MSJH.TTC,Microsoft JhengHei UI,128,96
MSJH.TTC,Microsoft JhengHei UI
MSYH.TTC,Microsoft YaHei UI,128,96
MSYH.TTC,Microsoft YaHei UI
MALGUN.TTF,Malgun Gothic,128,96
MALGUN.TTF,Malgun Gothic
MINGLIU.TTC,PMingLiU
SIMSUN.TTC,SimSun
GULIM.TTC,Gulim
YUGOTHM.TTC,Yu Gothic UI,128,96
YUGOTHM.TTC,Yu Gothic UI
SEGUISYM.TTF,Segoe UI Symbol
```

So simsun isn't even the first font it will fall through to: it's the 11<sup>th</sup>.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I wanted. So when, lets say, an alert comes up, it will try each of these out until one is found that contains valid glyphs for the entire text block? Also I'm surprised this question got voted down, this is a simple question with a fairly unknown answer.

Comment: probably because it wasn't a programming question. It's basically a general windows question so maybe superuser would have been the better place for it. Still, here we are, and the answer is yes: this is effectively the [Uniscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniscribe) configuration, where it will fall through each font one by one to check for glyph support. But not for an entire text block, text engines do this on a per-codepoint basis, so a mixed language sentence will use SimSun for the Chinese and Segoe UI for the Latin content.

Comment: @mike-pomax-kamermans Do you know of a place where this is documented?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology#font-linking